# What am I doing wrong here with these quotes?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, double-quotes, single-quotes

It's saying that the quote **'** after **test.bat** and before **)** is invalid syntax in the first **system_call()**. . How can I fix this? I don't seem to be doing anything wrong. (I **am** new to Python.)

```
import os

import subprocess

def system_call(command):

r = subprocess.call("cmd.exe /K " + "%s" % command,shell=False)
print (r)

system_call(r 'echo “@ECHO OFF\nECHO.\nECHO\n This is a batch file\nECHO.\nPAUSE\nCLS\nEXIT” > C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.bat ')

system_call('cd C:\Users\User\Desktop\ ')

system_call('test')
```

Comment: One word: "smart quotes". Wait, that's two words :-) But why would you call `subprocess...echo` to create a file when Python has perfectly adequate file I/O stuff? In any case, a `cd` within a subprocess is unlikely to carry over into the next subprocess call.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the quotation marks surrounding this section of code,

```
“@ECHO OFF\nECHO.\nECHO\n This is a batch file\nECHO.\nPAUSE\nCLS\nEXIT”
```

Change to

```
"@ECHO OFF\nECHO.\nECHO\n This is a batch file\nECHO.\nPAUSE\nCLS\nEXIT"
```

Notice how the original quotes(your code) has a curve to them where as I replaced those with straight, non fancy quotations. In my experience the fancy ones can, at times, cause issues.

P.S. This is my first answer here on Stack over flow, so I'm taking a stab at it :) hope it helps

Comment: Didn't work... although I did change the quotation marks.

Comment: `s/In my experience/Every single time/` :-)